# Unexpected behavior in ListView with imageview in row with different layout_height for the list

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a listview, his row have two textview and a imageview.

This is the `XML` code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_home"
    style="@style/listview_general"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textFilterEnabled="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nue_panel"/>
```

Below of listview i have a floating layout that hidden when i do scroll (Like twitter).
When i set the listview height to wrap_content i have an issue, the imageview of rows (Generally the number 8, its above of the mentioned twitter layout) randomly gets an image of other listview row, and when i force the recicle of view doing scroll to top or bottom, the imageview.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: use ViewHolder and share your adapter code please

Comment: Im using a library (https://github.com/pedrovgs/Renderers) but i used it in other apps and works fine. I cant share my adapter code, sorry. But im sure the error its for the listview..its possible the adapter combined with this heigth do the bug?

Comment: Can you explain it more @mmlooloo